# Android Widget start activity and get its result

Tags: android

I have a widget it has a button which starts another activity and that activity has a edit text. I need to get what ever entered in this edit text in my widget class while finishing the activity

plz help.........
jibysthomas

Comment: Use static keyword like public static String editTextValue; the will be a global are can be access from anywhere in your project.

Comment: But after finish the activity how i can came to know it happend?,in my widget class?i need to get the data typed in the edit text as soon as the activity finishes how i can trigger it?

Comment: The widget will be still in your application context and so the value u assigned to the static variable..

Comment: can u have some example i cant get u ...............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AppWidgetProvider` is a `BroadcastReceiver` and cannot use `startActivityForResult()` or any other means to get a result from some activity. Instead, modify your activity to directly update the `RemoteViews` for the app widget.